# Out of Band Disk Partitioning and Tables

Tags: partitioning, gpt, disk-management, boot-partition

Our current methods of disk partitioning involve storing the partition layout on the disk itself, right along with the data.

It's easy to screw up the data in a disk : just wipe out the partition data. GPT fixes this somewhat, but the data of how it's partitioned is still sitting next to the data.

Can we not store the partition table in a flash memory chip on disk, in an Out of Band(OoB) manner? Provide an ATA command to query partitions, and to seek a specific sector in a specific partition, which the drive controller can translate to disk-absolute sector numbers and addresses. Compatibility would not be a problem : the disk would switch into partitioned mode  using a specific command. Else it would just spoof the relevant sectors for the partition table, or better, it'll use current way of storing table with data. This way, protection for writing to partition table info can be achieved...

**UPDATE**

PROPOSAL :

- Store Partition table AND partition table querying code ON disk in a tiny flash chip.
- Reading through usual ATA commands.
- Modifying partition table requires new ATA commands
- Writing a new scheme of partitioning requires other new commands.
- Compatibility layer for seamless operation with non-OoB-partitioning-aware systems.

BENEFITS :

- GPT uses a maximum of 34 sectors twice on 512 byte sectors. 34KB.
- Reduces risk of overwriting or losing partition data
- Disk can be partitioned in ANY WAY : the ATA commands will take care, using routines stored
- Makes disks a lot more portable, OS not required to bother about it
- Standard methods to write to flash, both for modifying, and flashing new partitioning schemes

Comment: This would be a question for a Hard Drive engineer, and it is very theoretical. I believe it is off topic for this site.

Comment: I thought so, I did check the cs.se stack, where it didn't fit in either. Would it be on topic in any other SE?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange

Comment: We have no problem with theoretical questions asking for something to be explained (cc @alex), but I'm missing the specific question here. It seems you've given the answer yourself. What precisely do you need to know, or what technical aspect are you curious about?

Comment: I'm asking a design question. Is metadata best stored with the data? Or separately? Disk partitioning is a sub topic in its own right, and I believe the considerations that go into it should be some part of computer hardware. Hardware design? All the meta questions about any hardware point to SU.

Comment: However, in your considered decision if it's off topic, so be it. It is quite specific after all.

Comment: This just moves the problem from magnetic to electronic storage. All I know is that the size of memory this would require would increase the price of the drive by a sigificant amount.  If it was a good idea it likely would have already been done.

Comment: @Ramhound updated.

Comment: You do understand this website isn't a discussion forum right?

Answer (score 3):

This is in line with a classic, recurring problem in computers in general - is it better to store metadata (i.e. "data about data" - esp. things like "what type is this data") in the same stream as the data itself or separately?

If the flash chip holding the hardware information is read/write accessible just as much as sector 0 of the hard drive, you really haven't bought yourself any additional protection.  It's just as easy to trash the partition flash storage as it is sector 0, and only marginally harder to avoid.

You've introduced additional complexity, firmware development needs and manufacturing cost for little benefit.

"Locking" and such - I guess it'd be nice to make provision for a BIOS to lock a drive's partition table, but I'm really more worried about the data in the partition rather than the partition itself.  I'd also like to be able to change the partitions and switch hard drives without potentially having to ask my future DRM-enabled BIOS for permission.

One thing that studying networking has taught me is that sometimes for a device or service to say "nothing is my job but this one task" is really the best and most robust thing.  We want hard drive designers and manufacturers to concentrate on one thing - reliable, copious storage.  If you don't have that, little else matters in a computer.  Letting everything else (partitioning, security, etc.) to be "not the drive's job" allows the drive itself to be a reliable, replaceable, easily upgradeable and expandable commodity.

Comment: What if partition table accessing routines were also stored on disk? btw, none of this is under the control of the BIOS, I wasn't clear enough before. Please check update.

Comment: Plus, it's nice to pull the drive out, put it in another machine and be able to see the contents. Kind of stinks to have hardware go out and lose your data. Had that happen on a Compaq Deskpro M that had hardware lock-in and was running as a server. You have no recourse if your BIOS stored partition table snuffs it.

Comment: @FiascoLabs It was in that interest itself I thought of this. The partition table would be stored in flash on disk.

Comment: @MilindR - What benefit would that provide?  The speed of the data bus is already faster then we can process it.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not about speed. Safety is more like it. Analogous to prepared statements in SQL.

Comment: Also, please note nothing is stopping you from backing up your partition table on your own now, if you are really worried about some random process, etc. wiping it out.

Comment: @MilindR - prepared statements are about speed not safety.  parameterized sql statements are about safety.  The fact prepared statements are parameterized is simply a bonus.

Comment: @Ramhound [But they prevent SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Although EFI doesn't do this, it does do something similar with boot loader data: Boot loaders are stored on disk, but information about which boot loader to launch is stored in NVRAM. IMHO, this has been a disaster, because it creates *two* points of failure for the boot process. I'm sure something similar would happen if partitioning data were separated as the question suggests.

Comment: @MilindR - I can prevent SQL Injection without the use of Stored Procedures.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not the point, it's the principle of separating template and data programmatically so that data can't just overwrite the template. Same with disk partitioning. It's a cleaner approach in a sense.

Comment: @RodSmith Wouldn't this work in exactly the opposite way, with an abstracted way of accessing partitions using ATA commands? This means that partitioning will be at least as reliable as it is today, since <100KB of flash can be made as resilient as required with no real cost. The data will also be as reliable as it is today since it resides on disk in the same way as before. With a non-supporting OS, writing to the partition table in such a disk can be prohibited, and when reading, those sectors can be faked.

Comment: Even if the flash is in the same physical enclosure as the disk, it's a different type of medium, which has different failure modes from the disk medium it's meant to serve. Statistically speaking, there's no way that can be more reliable than what we have now. The main advantage would be in isolating the partition data from general I/O operations. I admit there is some merit to that suggestion, but it's something you'd need to put into a standard, and I'm skeptical it would improve reliability, in practice. Our talking about it here won't make it happen, so it's a pointless discussion.